# How to convert a column of numeric IDs to letters?

Tags: qgis, data, features, attribute-table

I'm working with qgis 1.8.0. I divided a map into 500 features (small rectangles), and now I have the doubt if there is any way to change the ID of the attributes from numbers to letters? When I did the division of the original map, each of the 500 divisions got one numeric ID (please refer to column 3 of image) and now I'm trying to load that map to STATPLANET PLUS and when working with that program, the ID may not be numerical. Any ideas?

Regards!!
actual attribute table
[image: image of attribute table with column 3 showing integer values.]
[image: configuration settings used on field calculator]

Comment: Why not just use the field calculator to convert `CVE_ENT` to character type? You can even make it overtly alphanumeric by, say, prepending some common prefix to it, such as converting `28` to `"ID28"`, etc. That should satisfy any software that insists the key be alphanumeric.

Comment: @whuber, I tried to do the conversions with the field calculator, with the "tostring" tool under the conversions menu. What I did saw like this: tostring("ID"), then another column was created but was a numeric one, with the same values of the ID column, any conversion was done. I attached a picture of the settings I used on the field calculator, would you have an idea why is that happening?!

Comment: From the left-justification of the entries in the [Name] field in your illustration, I infer that the operation completed correctly and that all ids were indeed converted to text exactly as you had requested.

Comment: @user20159, in Expression window I try write "ID" (or tostring("ID")) - I receive attributes from numerical field in new text field. Try as write /whuber/ write in Expression window 'ID' ||  "ID" for result "ID28", etc.

Comment: @whuber ... ok I think I have it now. Just one other thing, how can I add the common prefix you mentioned in your first comment?

Comment: In the Field Calculator dialog, look within the string functions for a concatenation operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach to this, which may not be the simplest, will still get you where you need to be.  If you absolutely need to have letters for unique identified, I would create a CSV with two columns: ID and LetterID.  ID will be numbers 1-500 and LetterID will be a two character string.  There are 676 possible letter combinations with two characters and 26 letters of the alphabet.

To create the list of letters, write a simple python script with embedded for loops.  This is a quick, lazy one I just wrote:

```
first = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
second = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

f = open ('UniqueLetter.txt', 'w')

for a in first:
    for b in second:
        f.write(a+b+ '\n')

f.close()
```

Copy the values of your text doc into excel, crop to 500 values and add your join field (1-500). Save as CSV, import to QGIS, join to your shapefile and save or use field calculator to copy the unique letter combinations into a new field.